# Android - Uploading Image with Multipart Retrofit Failed or Crash

Tags: android, upload, rx-java, multipartform-data, retrofit2

I try to make an upload image with Retrofit Mulitpart Android. But I still get my app error.

This is how to get the image

```
 private final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;

      private void startGallery() {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/png");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
    }
```

this is the onActivityResult and the way i request to upload the image

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                File file = new File(selectedImage.getPath());

                RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("image/png"), file);

                // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
                MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("DocTyp01", file.getName(), reqFile);

                getApi().uploadByCustomer(PrefHelper.getString(PrefKey.TOKEN), "DocTyp01", body)
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe(new Observer<GenericResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                               dismissProgressDialog();
                                Timber.e(e.getMessage());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNext(GenericResponse response) {
                            dismissProgressDialog();
                                if (response.getCode() == 0) {
                                 showSuccessDialog("Saving success", false);
                                }

                            }
                        });
            }


            }
    }
```

this is the API Service

```
    @Multipart
    @POST(PORTAL_URL + "customerDocument/uploadByCustomer")
    Observable<GenericResponse> uploadByCustomer(@Part("token") String token,
                                                 @Part("type") String type,
                                                 @Part MultipartBody.Part requestBodyFile);
```

And Sometimes the log didn't show me the error, and also I got no response from API, it makes me hard to find the error. Please, help me to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: response from api is "file is not found", and i see on debugger contentType is null. it should be filled "DocTyp01" if i test it on Rest Client @yosriz

Comment: Please attach a log of the errors

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                File file = new File(selectedImage.getPath());
                RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
                MultipartBody.Part multipartBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();

                RetroInterface retroInterface = retrofit.create(RetroInterface.class);
                Call<ResponseBody> call = retroInterface.uploadPhoto(token, multipartBody);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: i use RxJava Observable. So it's not gonna work for my code